# How to initialize jsp tags with custom value?

Tags: java, jsp

I have some jsp tags for producing translation of strings, e.g `<x:lang name="hello" />` will produce the translation of 'hello' in the given language. The problem is, I need to be able to pass the language, and the name of the file, to the tags class, before it can happen.

Is there a thread-safe way of passing on any parameters to the tags class at the top of the file, which it will then remember and use for all future tags in that class?

For example, at the top of my file, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<x:myTag lang="english" file="signup" />
```

After that, whenever I do `<x:myTag string="something" />`, it should know that I'm referring to English language, and to look in the file 'signup' for the strings.

Is that possible?

Comment: Store the language in user session, then retrieve it using EL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`<c:set>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) from JSTL with the scope `request`.

```
<c:set scope="request" var="lang" value="english" />
```

Then in the tag, you can use the value of the var with EL: `${lang}`.

---

Edit: Added a more complete example.

The JSP page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<body>
   <c:set scope="request" var="lang" value="english" />
   <x:hello />
</body>
</html>
```

And in the hello tag:

```
<c:choose>
 <c:when test="${lang eq 'english'}">Hello World!</c:when>
 <c:when test="${lang eq 'french'}">Bonjour le monde !</c:when>
</c:choose>
```

If you use java tags, you can get the value with:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) pageContext.getRequest();
String lang = (String) request.getAttribute("lang");
```

Comment: My question is, do I need to specify these variables with every tag, or if I specify it at the top of the file, then will it assume those values for every future time that i call the tag?

Comment: You set the variable in the main page, and can use the variable inside the tags (for a given request).

Comment: Lets say `<myTag>` requires the parameter `foo`. Will I need to specify this `foo` parameter each time I call `<myTag>`, e.g by doing `<myTag foo="${someVar}" />` or is there a way to set the default value of `foo` on `myTag` for the current request, so each time in future when I call  `<myTag />` I won't need to specify `foo`?

Comment: In the same request, you don't have to specify the parameter. I'll update the answer with a more comprehensive example.

Comment: Let me be more clear. In my case, my tag output is being generated by a java class. In this java class I have a private variable called `foo`. I need a value for `foo` whenever `doTag()` of my tag is called from jsp. My question is, will the same instance of my tag's class be used to generate the output each time within the same request, so if I specify the value of `foo` once, it will remember that value from before?

Comment: It's not so simple if you use java tags. I've updated the answer with the code you need to get the value.

Comment: Thanks, but the value is not coming from the request. I want to specify the value at the top of my jsp file, and then have the java tag class remember it for the rest of the request whenever i call the tag again.. is that possible?

Comment: That's what the `<c:set>` do in the JSP.

Comment: Ah.. so if I do `<c:set />` this will set the attribute in the request, which I can retrieve from `request.getAttribute()` in the java class?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly that.